# Random-function complie by C to DLL work incorectly

Tags: c++, excel, vba

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
float randomnumber(double x)
{
// when input a number(x). Ex 99.5
// this function will return ramdom a (double)number between 98.2%*x to 101.8%*x
     double a = 0;
     srand(time(0));
     a = (1 + rand() % 36) / 1000;
     return x * (0.982 + a);
}
float _stdcall randnumber(double x)
{
     double a = 0;
     do
     {
         a = randomnumber(x);
     }while (a > 100 || a == 100);

     return a;
}
```

def file

```
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS
RandNum = randnumber
```

I call it in excel-vba as function. When i use it, it randoms corectly in first time, but ...
When i calculate workbook manually (Fress F9 or re-enter), it does not change number.
Why it does not work?

Comment: `(1 + rand()) % 36 / 1000;` is integer arithmetic

Comment: i don't understand
a = (1 + rand() % 36) / 1000; /* just like double formating*/
and i run it correctly in simple empty project. P/s sr (1 + rand() % 36) / 1000 not (1 + rand()) % 36 / 1000;, it my mistake :D

Answer (score 1):

srand(time(NULL)) is based on the current time in seconds. So if you call it in less than a second, it will give you the same seed.

To solve this problem you could increase the precision of the time structure used by srand.

```
#include <sys/time.h>

struct timeval t1;
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
srand(t1.tv_usec * t1.tv_sec);
```

This answer gives more info on the [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343909/6374665)

Comment: Tks for your support. I've found my problem, but I forget that reply your answer.
this mistake is caused by un-force formating number '1000' as double and  precision of time structure in seconds.